# observe() called more than once

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-viewmodel, android-navigation, android-mvvm

In this case, I have two fragments in BottomNavigationView: Home and Dictionary.

Inside of DictionaryFragment I show [BottomSheetFragment](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#bottom-sheets) with EditText and Button. When the user clicks to the button, the following code executing:

```kotlin
if (name.isNotEmpty()) {
    sharedViewModel.setNewPackName(name)
}
```

where *name* is text from EditText and **SharedViewModel:**

```kotlin
val currentPackName = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun setNewPackName(packName: String) {
    currentPackName.postValue(packName)
}
```

Inside of DictionaryFragment I have this code:

```kotlin
override fun setObservers() {
    sharedViewModel.currentPackName.observe { newPackName ->
        Timber.tag("newName").d("setObservers(): $newPackName")
        pack_name.text = newPackName
    }
}
```

But when I moving *DictionaryFragment* -> *HomeFragment* -> *DictionaryFragment*, I see duplicate of "setObservers(): $newPackName" string in my Logcat. Repeating these steps (D-> H-> D) I see the same situation: the next line is printed

**BaseViewModel**

```kotlin
open class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {

   val compositeDisposable by lazy { CompositeDisposable() }

    protected fun <T : Any> Observable<T>.compositeSubscribe(
        onNext: (T) -> Unit = {},
        onError: (Throwable) -> Unit = {},
        onComplete: () -> Unit = {}
    ) = composite(
        subscribe(onNext, onError, incomplete)
    )

    private fun composite(disposable: Disposable) {
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
        super.onCleared()
    }  
}
```

To be honest, I don’t know what could be the problem. I also use [Navigation architecture Component](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) where the visual state of the fragments is preserved, but the life cycle methods are called again.

**EDIT:** This problem occurs if I have `viewModel.smth.observe()` and when I switch between fragments (for example, D -> H -> D)

**EDIT_2:** In my *BaseFragment* I have the following extension function:

```kotlin
protected inline fun <T> LiveData<T>.observe(crossinline codeBlock: (T) -> Unit) {
    observe(this@BaseFragment, Observer { it -> it?.let { codeBlock(it) } })
}
```

I've tried to change it to:

```kotlin
protected inline fun <T> LiveData<T>.observe(crossinline codeBlock: (T) -> Unit) {
    val observer = Observer<T> { it -> it?.let { codeBlock(it) } }
    removeObserver(observer)
    observe(this@BaseFragment, observer)
}
```

but the problem is still here.

Please, help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Where is the setObservers() method defined and where and when is it invoked?

Comment: @ADM, trying to figure out

Comment: @Ridcully, it's open fun defined in BaseFragment and invoked in onViewCreated()

Comment: edited my question with **EDIT_2**

Comment: @ADM, thank you, it works fine with the third method in this article. But can I somehow do this with inline function? It’s not very nice to create a separate object each time